# Handling Dynamic Sample Rates when Saving Audio File

Tags: naudio

So, I am recording a WAVE file using 16-bit PCM samples that are received from a *widget* that streams them over in real time.  Pretty basic stuff, right?  Except the problem is that the widget might dynamically **change the sample rate of the audio data** that it is sending.

It might start out at a nice 44.1 kHz stream but then might change to a 23 kHz sample rate, or vice-versa.  My understanding is that conventional WAVE files do not handle varying sample rates like this, so I am trying to determine the best way to handle the situation.

One approach I came up with was to put something like a `ResamplerDmoStream` in front of the `WaveFileWriter`, locking the `WaveFileWriter` to a sample rate of 44.1 kHz, and just resampling all incoming data to 44.1 kHz.

Another idea that might work is to find a supported output file format that may have *native support for varying sample rates*, write all the data to that file and then perform a post-process resampling step to create a conventional 44.1 kHz WAVE file.

Anyone else out there had to deal with this kind of situation and has a better idea?

Thanks!

Peace!

Comment: Generally audio files should have the same sample rate throughout, and WAV certainly doesn't support changes. The approach of resampling to a common format would be the best approach, or simply starting a new file whenever you get a sample rate change

Comment: Thanks.  I figured as much - resampling is the way to go as I cannot keep creating new files as this happens.